How to integrate AWS Lambda to Application Load Balanced Fargate Service
I'm trying to protect an endpoint (e.g., /protected) in my API hosted on an application load balanced Fargate service (ALB) using a JWTAuthorizer Lambda function.
But I couldn't really find a good example that showing how can I do it. So far I tried:
private createContainerCopilotService() {

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this.stack, 'Cluster', {
        vpc: this.stack.resources.external.vpc,
        clusterName: `${this.config.getStackName()}-Cluster`,
        containerInsights: true,
    });


    const loadBalancedFargateService = new ecsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this.stack, 'LoadBalancedService', {
        cluster,
        memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
        desiredCount: 1,
        cpu: 512,
        publicLoadBalancer: true,
        redirectHTTP: true,
        protocol: aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
        taskImageOptions: {
            image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset('.',
                {
                    file: 'src/docker/Dockerfile',
                    buildArgs: { NODE_VERSION: '20' },
                },
            ),
            environment: {
                // Env variables
            },
        },
        loadBalancerName: `${this.config.getStackName()}-LoadBalancer`,
        domainName: this.config.getDomainName(),
        domainZone: this.stack.resources.external.hostedZone,
        securityGroups: [this.stack.resources.external.consumerOpenSearchAccessSecurityGroup],
    });

    loadBalancedFargateService.targetGroup.configureHealthCheck({
        path: '/',
    });

    return loadBalancedFargateService;
}

private createApiGateway(loadBalancedFargateService: ecsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService) {

    const api = new apigw2.HttpApi(this.stack, 'HttpGateWay');

    const jwtAuthorizerFunction = lambda.Function.fromFunctionAttributes(
        this.stack,
        'ImportedJwtAuthorizer',
        {
            functionArn: this.config.getAuthorizerLambdaArn(),
            skipPermissions: true,
        }
    );

    const jwtAuthorizerIntegration = new apigw.LambdaIntegration(jwtAuthorizerFunction);

    api.addRoutes({
        path: '/sessions/{proxy+}',
        methods: [apigw2.HttpMethod.GET],
        integration: new apigw2Integrations.HttpAlbIntegration('AuthIntegration', loadBalancedFargateService.listener,
            {
                // Here I don't know how can I use the jwtAuthorizerIntegration
            }
        )
    })
}

Does anyone have experience with connecting Lambda functions to ALBs. Shall I use API Gateway or any suggestions on how to properly secure the endpoint using the Lambda authorizer?

You need it in the "authorizer" argument, not in "integration". The term to search is "custom lambda authorizer" (for example,  this tutorial or the official docs )

@defaultUsernameN thank you for your answer.  I followed the guide but I'm still couldn't understand how can I make the communication between Alb and API Gateway.. I tried couple of things but stuck with target group does not have an associated load balancer

ALB could be in front of APIGW or behind it, which is your case? If second here's a related question - that setup, as far as I see,  would not interfere with the lambda authorizer.

And generally, I assume you know why you want it that way... but using simultaneously APIGW and ALB is kind of an unusual setup (though not unheard of) - are you totally sure it's what you want? what was the original problem you were solving?

@defaultUsernameN Actually I wasn't really planning to use APIGW I just wanted to use the lambda function to protect /sessions/** endpoints.  APIGW was something I read make lambda implementation easy. If do you think it's unnecessary I would happily remove it. I just want to when a request come to /sessions lambda should check the Authorization header.

Oh ok. Any reason you wouldn't use Cognito+ALB instead of the APIGW idea? That's the usual route for this kind of thing

@defaultUsernameN my company uses the same lambda authorizer and I wanted to use it here as well. I thought it would be easy. But maybe I would just use the lambda for sessions operations as well. It would be a smoother solution.

check the lib aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigatewayv2-authorizers: and import this class HttpLambdaAuthorizer
after creating the authorizer you can attach it in a way similar to this:
    const apiGateway = new HttpApi(this, "ApiGateway", {
        corsPreflight: {
            allowHeaders: ["*"],
            allowCredentials: true,
            allowMethods: [
                CorsHttpMethod.PATCH,
                CorsHttpMethod.POST,
                CorsHttpMethod.GET,
                CorsHttpMethod.PUT,
                CorsHttpMethod.DELETE,
                CorsHttpMethod.OPTIONS,
            ],
            allowOrigins: ["*"
            ],
            maxAge: cdk.Duration.days(1),
        },
        defaultAuthorizer: lambdaAuthorizer,
    });


Thank you for your response. But I think I need a vpc as well.

yes, but the vpc must be defined on your cluster and on your ALB, no need that config for api gateway. If you need that your lambda authorizer runs into a vpc, you should put that  on  jwtAuthorizerFunction (using this properties: vpc, securityGroups and vpcSubnets)
